# Why do duplicate folders exist in my Azure blob storage container?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am aware that Azure blob storage does not use an actual folder structure but could not think of a better way to describe this.

The issue we're seeing is when opening Server Explorer (in Visual Studio) to browse through our blob storage container. We separate client resources and data by folder so in this case we have a blob titled `productdata/Client_5/testimage.jpg`.

The problem is that this `Client_5` folder appears twice when inspecting our blob storage. So far I've double checked there are no weird special characters in either folder and double checked case sensitivity. The two paths are EXACTLY the same except its actual contents. Our application has no problems with this because the path is still exactly the same to the resources it's attempting to get. (For example, since the folders are named exactly the same, `https://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/productdata/Client_5/image.jpg` still takes us to exactly where we need to be.) It's just a pain when we use Server Explorer to view our blobs on Azure because we have two folder locations to check. This could very well be a bug in Server Explorer for Visual Studio as well.

If anyone else has ever come across this, any info is appreciated. I couldn't find anything on the topic when searching online but figure I would post the question here for reference. Also, I'll be contacting Azure support soon to see if they can shed some light on any of this and will post what info I get from them here later.

Comment: Do you see similar behavior in other storage explorers as well? Could be a bug with Server Explorer.

Comment: Good point.. Azure Storage Explorer crashes when trying to load but I'll see if I can find another way to view the contents other than Server Explorer.

Comment: Try Azure Explorer from Cerebrata - http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-explorer/introduction.

Comment: That Azure Explorer is able to browse through our containers and only one folder is shown. Seems to be a bug in Server Explorer after all. Thanks for your help on troubleshooting this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that blob storage doesn't have the concept of folder but the API built on the top of it does. I've seen exactly the same or similar problems in other tools as well: Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and even Azure Portal. I tried to go deeper and when I executed:

```
CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs(null, useFlatBlobListing: false)
```

it also returned duplicated directories. To be precise it returned the list with several instances of `CloudBlobDirectory` that had the same `Prefix`. Sounds like a bug. Now, if a tool uses this approach to get a list of directories it will fail. If the tool uses flat listing and builds the structure of folders in its logic it should be ok.

Hard to say what is the reason of such behaviour. In my case files in blob storage were copied by Azure Data Factory activity with concurrency option but I'm not sure if it's the rule.

BTW Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer in my case showed only some subset of folders which is much worse than displaying duplicated directories so I switched to Azure Explorer mentioned above and it's worth recommending.

Comment: Although this isn't a problem anymore, your answer has provided much insight into this. Marking it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing an issue where the "folder" names appeared identical, but on closer inspection one had a trailing space.

Because folders don't really exist in blob storage and a space is a valid value, it is possible to have trailing or leading spaces in the names.

Answer (score 0):

Azure blob storage does not ahve the concept of folder, only container, you can simulate folder setting the name of the blog to save like '**folder/img.png**', but **folder/** is part of the name of the blob.

Also, I ever use Storage Explorer, try with this: http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/releases/view/125870

Comment: `Azure blob storage does not ahve the concept of folder` ... this is the 1st line said in the question

Comment: Yes, I'm aware blob storage does not use folders. We're simulating the folders. I just couldn't think of a better way to word the question. In any case, Azure Storage Explorer is able to load our smaller containers but crashes when trying to view our much larger containers.